# How do I diagram this sentence in a tree diagram?

Tags: syntax

You must complete your research paper before I can give you a grade.

*Having challenges with before.

Comment: Think "subordinate conjunction introducing a tensed clause".

Comment: @anna you should at least show us what you have done. You can use http://ironcreek.net/phpsyntaxtree/ for drawing diagrams, or http://eztreesee.coli.uni-saarland.de/ for parsing the whole thing in software.

Answer (score 1):

It's not easy.  I'd let the logic dictate the syntactic structure.

> [ necessarily [ A will precede B ] ]

where A = you complete your research paper, B = I can give you a grade, necessarily is expressed with "must", and precede is expressed with "before".

It's going to be a challenge getting from the above to a single tree structure that directly represents your problem sentence. I'm not sure it's possible.

Good luck.